# Login actions take so long (Syslog issue)

Tags: linux, authentication, syslog, rsyslog

**A symptom:**

Every login action like ssh, su, sudo or even a exit by a user take near a minute long.

A **SSH** call is slow here:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

And if i do **strace -f su - juan ls** process is slow here:

```
open("/etc/login.defs", O_RDONLY)       = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10551, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2c32202000
read(4, "#\n# /etc/login.defs - Configurat"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, " issuing \n# the \"mesg y\" command"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, " algorithm compatible with the o"..., 4096) = 2359
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f2c32202000, 4096)            = 0
sendto(3, "<86>Feb 10 17:36:33 su[4088]: + "..., 52, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0
```

The problem is here, when a process tried to write to **/dev/log**:

```
12:12:23 connect(1, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0 <0.000008>
12:12:23 sendto(1, "<13>Feb 11 12:12:23 juan: hello "..., 37, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 37 <15.931766>
```

Debug of **rsyslog**:

```
2042.323399028:7f5a60003700: --------imuxsock calling select, active file descriptors (max 4): 0 4 
2042.323419636:7f5a60003700: Message from UNIX socket: #0
2042.323434226:7f5a60003700: main Q: queue nearly full (10000 entries), but could not drop msg (iRet: 0, severity 6)
2042.323437267:7f5a60003700: main Q: doEnqSingleObject: queue FULL - waiting 2000ms to drain.
2044.323585582:7f5a60003700: main Q: doEnqSingleObject: cond timeout, dropping message!
2044.323616781:7f5a60003700: main Q: EnqueueMsg advised worker start
```

**/var/log/syslog** and **/var/log/messages** are empty

Answer (score 1):

As you properly explained on your question the problem is on the logging part, you get one socket (1) for /dev/log, then use it to sendto a silly message "hello juan", but it takes 15 seconds.

I'm seeing the same with a vsftpd, its nothing about the service itself, the problem is with your rsyslog. Probably if you restart it the 15 seconds will go down to almost nothing, but it will build up over time.

Also, your rsyslog queue is nearly full, which means that your remote server is not working or your disk where you write the logs is utterly slow, my guess is with the remote option.

This is an important message :

`doEnqSingleObject: queue FULL - waiting 2000ms to drain.`

I can not provide more information since I'm here because I have my own problems, but maybe changing the queue type could help.

https://www.rsyslog.com/?s=queue

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a wide variety of reasons, I would suggest a good place to start debugging this would be to use the -vvv argument to output a more detailed trace of what is happening, you should hopefully then be able to spot which part of the process it is hanging on

so your command should look something like : ssh foo@domain.com -vvv

Comment: The SSH stay here for a while:  
  
  
`debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).  

...........  

debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com  
debug1: Entering interactive session.  `

Comment: Does it hang on the Authentication part or when entering Interactive session ? 

If it's the Auth part then I think the issue could be related to GSSAPI, if you're not using that then you can disable it by adding the following "GSSAPIAuthentication no" to /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: You'll also need to reload ssh by using the following command once you've saved the changes

`# service ssh reload`

or if you're using Fedora, RHEL or CentOS I think you'll need to use 

`# service sshd reload` instead.... the difference being `sshd` instead of `ssh`

Comment: don't looks like a SSH issue, the bug is the same for any login action, even su, sudo, exit......

Comment: Unfortunately there's only 2 other things I can think could be culprits and they are 1. Sys log daemon behaving oddly 2. Reverse Dns issue ..... I'd be clutching at straws if these aren't the issue, you can test if the daemon is the problem if  logger 'hello world' takes a long time to respond too... Usually if this is the case simply restart Syslog with "service rsyslog restart" and then check if that solves the issue.  Apologies for poor formatting I'm currently using my mobile

Comment: you are right, logger is slow but restart syslog-ng do not solves the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the issue of slow acceptance to a ssh session could have multiple reasons for the cause. It depends on whether the user you are logging on is locally based or ldap or AD based.
ssh with -vvv is a good option to check the ssh with max debugging log level, that will give you best idea where it is getting hanged.
Please check the number of hops in between the server from where you trying to login the server through traceroute.

Comment: Is not a SSH or network issue , local actions like su or sudo are slow

Comment: It seens the problem could be due to selinux then.. Here's some more information: Check in /var/log/audit.log and if found a bunch of avc denials until, finally, it gives up and lets the "su" proceed. Use this link for more info http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Re...ide/#id2839255 which suggests that the selinux context will be wrong for home directories that aren't in /home, which seems to be your situation at the moment.

Comment: looks like an issue when writing to /dev/log